# Integral of $x/\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have been attempting to solve for the integral of the below equation but have had no luck so far.  After searching online I have only managed to find one mention of it but with no explanation (the below picture).

I have tried using the quotient rule by parts formula, and substitution but have found myself running circles each time and getting nowhere near the proposed answer on the site.  I need this integral for a larger integral I'm doing but need to know its proof so I may properly explain its use in my paper.

I know I'm not really providing much here, but I've become completely lost with this integral.  Any help is much appreciated.

[image: http://www.sosmath.com/tables/integral/integ11/img3.gif]

Comment: **Hint:** $t=x^2+a^2$.

Comment: Next time, just state the problem in short

Comment: The formula in the title subtracts $x^2$ from $a^2$, but the formula in the picture in the question body adds $x^2$ to $a^2$. Which integral do you want?

Comment: The _proof_ of the equation in the picture is simply the fact that the derivative of the expression on the right-hand side of the equation is the expression inside the integral on the left-hand side. What do you need other than that to "explain its use" in your paper?

Comment: Welcome to Maths.SE! Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures cannot be searched and are inaccessible to those using screen readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u = x^2+a^2$ as has been suggested. Then $\frac{du}{dx} = 2x$ or equivalently $dx = \frac{du}{2x}$. Substituting these quantities into the integral gives

\begin{align}
 \int \frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}} du = \sqrt{u} + C = \sqrt{x^2+a^2} + C
\end{align}

Comment: Okay this fixes a lot, because I tried using t = a^2 +x^2 but I messed up on the substitution.  Silly mistake, but thanks a lot, you and Lucian help a lot Ill accept answer in a sec after i look this over a bit and properly understand what I did wrong.

Comment: @23scurtu No problem, let me know if you don't understand something.

Answer (score 2):

You need only the "fundamental theorem of calculus" here!

Note that
$$
\int_{x} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+a^{2}}} = \int_{x}D(x^{2}+a^{2})^{1/2} = (x^{2}+a^{2})^{1/2} + \text{some constant}.
$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29028/discussion-on-answer-by-gudson-chou-integral-of-x-sqrta2-x2).

Answer (score 1):

Let's use U-substitution to solve this problem!

> $$\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+a^{2}}}dx$$

$$\text{Let: }\qquad u = x^2+a^2\quad \text{and}\quad du = 2xdx$$

Therefore,
\begin{align}
\require{cancel}\\
\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+a^{2}}}dx &= \frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt u}du\\
&= \frac{1}{\cancel2} (\cancel2\sqrt u) + C\\
&= \sqrt u + C\\
&= \sqrt{x^2+a^2} + C\\
\end{align}

Comment: when you canceled out the 2, I thought that there was only one 2 that came from the 1/2.  where did the second one come from?

Comment: The $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt u}du$ is $2\sqrt u + C$. Do you want me to explicitly have that worked out in the answer?

Comment: Oh crap! I see how it works.  raising the power to the u^-1/2 requires multiplying by 2 to cancel out the 1/2 that would be carried down through the derivation of u^1/2.  Adding that would prob help anyone else coming by this question.

Comment: @23scurtu Don't think of it as multiplying by 2 to cancel out the $\frac{1}{2}$ in the long run, just think of the short term integral, $\int u^{-\frac{1}{2}}du=\frac{u^{-\frac{1}{2}+1}}{-\frac{1}{2}+1}=\frac{u^{\frac{1}{2}}}{\frac{1}{2}}=2u^{\frac{1}{2}} = 2\sqrt u$.

Comment: alright thankks